# Asymmetrical Groff output

Tags: groff, tbl

For years, I've been generating tables created with raw Groff commands. All I did was
groff -t file >file.ps, and I got what I wanted. The administrator upgraded gnu utilities, and now the same scripts produce output on a page that seems longer and narrower than before. The output is now asymmetrical. What do I do?

Thank you,
Robert Katz

Comment: There's not much info to go on. Perhaps the default paper size has changed. This is configured globally in a file. You can try overriding it by adding option `-dpaper=a4` to the groff command to use iso A4 paper. See `man papersize` for other names.

Comment: I tried this: groff -Tps -P-pletter.That worked. In the file '/usr/share/groff/1.22.4/font/devps/DESC/', there is a line 'papersize /etc/papersize a4', but there is no file /etc/papersize.  Thank you.